# Determine when a page has finished loading when using WebBrowser view in WPF (Windows.Controls.WebBrowser)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I've used the "LoadCompleted" event and basically once the event is received, I need to take a screenshot of the screen (which I've built). The problem is once this event goes out, the screenshot is just blank (page hasn't loaded yet) and only if I put a delay of 5-10 seconds, the screenshot will work

Now how can I determine when the webpage is fully rendered? That all the aspects are loaded and so on

Comment: from where and when u are raising LoadCompleted event?

Comment: I'm not raising it, it's being raised by the browser but it gets fired too early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the LoadCompleted event is called immediately after the page has been loaded, but before it has been rendered. I don't know of any way to tell exactly when it's finished rendering, but you can use the Dispatcher to ensure your code is run after any rendering has occurred.

```
private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(TakeScreenshot, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}

private void TakeScreenshot()
{
    //insert your screenshot code here
}
```

You might have to experiment with the priority level a bit, but Background seems to be doing the trick for me.